# Need to copy code of an existing TFS project/solution to create a new TFS project/solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I did review several of the suggested articles to see if this answer has been given or documented already, but didn't find anything that seemed to answer it.

My boss wants me to create a new Project Folder in an existing Group Project folder ($/GroupProj1/MyGroup/New) and copy all the existing code from an old Group Project ($/MyGroup/CommandProc/Dev) "using TFS" so that the history of each file is preserved, e.g. "View History" of "$/GroupProj1/MyGroup/New/Solution1/NewMe.cs" is copied from "$/MyGroup/CommandProc/Old/Dev/Solution/Me.cs" but retains the history, or at least some link to it's history in the previous solution.

1. Is that possible?
2. If so, how? i.e. point me to the right docs, or whatever.

If this *has* been answered previously, then please forgive my duplication and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to move source code with history across team project boundaries.

There are some ways you can do it if you don't mind losing some degree of fidelity (such as original check-in dates and the original committer).

The process I've used is:

1. Use [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) to convert the source TFVC repository into a Git repository, containing all of the history
2. Point the Git repo created in step #1 to the new destination team project and use git-tfs to convert the changes from Git commits to TFVC check-ins, which will "play back" the entire history, one commit at a time.

As stated earlier, you will lose some degree of fidelity in this process. Specifically, the check-in dates for everything will be the current time, and I believe the committer will be the person running git-tfs.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

I'll include this here, 'cause I don't think the two members of my group believed me at the time and I'm pretty sure they will never read this, but ...................................... wait for it.... 

 "I told you so."